# Box shadow is not appearing, no reference to it when I inspect element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a custom button with a border radius and box shadow. Here is my html and css

```
.selectOptionButton{
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 15px 2px #e7e6e0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 15px 2px #e7e6e0; 
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 15px 2px #e7e6e0; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px; 
  border-radius: 100px; 
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #e7e6e0;
}

<div class="selectOptionButton text-center">Test</div>
```

For some reason when i inspect the element i see this :

```
.selectOptionButton {
    background-color: #E7E6E0;
    border-radius: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? this works for me on Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/4Q3KV/

Comment: Your colour codes are too short (only 5 characters instead of 6): I assume `#e7e6e` should be `#e7e6e0`

Comment: Yo were right that the color was wrong, but that did not seem to fix the lack of shadow..

Comment: the JS fiddle you posted does not seem to work for me it looks exactly like my site does. My browser is firefox.

Comment: THis is starting to look my browser is the problem

Comment: @AndrewFont indeed, which firefox version are you using?

Comment: look below, you have an inset of color `#e7e6e0` on a background of color `#e7e6e0`  I couldn't see it until I changed the color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's an inset color that is the same as the background color

check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4DSw/) with

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset  0px 0px 15px 2px #333aaa;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px 2px #333aaa; 
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 15px 2px #333aaa;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the exact issue. I am surprised i missed this along with others lol.

Comment: you are welcome.  i actually removed the inset and then saw the color number wasn't long enough and and then I changed the color.  took me a couple of tries to get the contrast enough for me to see it

Comment: Funny how simple mistake can be so easy to over look